# optimizing "offset position on scroll" javascript snippet

Tags: javascript, css, optimization, scroll, position

I'm at a loss as to how I could optimize this bit of code. I realize I could place these objects into some sort of array, but I'm not sure how to go about this. Any guidance would be appreciated. I'm still learning, and stackoverflow has helped me greatly so far. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var $stripe01 = $('.stripe-01');
   var $stripe02 = $('.stripe-02');  
   var $stripe03 = $('.stripe-03');  
   var $stripe04 = $('.stripe-04');  
   var $stripe05 = $('.stripe-05');    
   var $stripe06 = $('.stripe-06');      

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
        d = $(document).height(),
        c = $(this).height();

    scrollPercent = (s / (d - c) * 18);
    scrollPercent02 = (s / (d - c) * 14);      
    scrollPercent03 = (s / (d - c) * 30);            
    scrollPercent04 = (s / (d - c) * 4);            

    var position01 = -(scrollPercent * ($(document).width() - $stripe01.width()));
    var position02 = -(scrollPercent02 * ($(document).width() - $stripe01.width()));
    var position03 = -(scrollPercent03 * -($(document).width() - $stripe03.width()));      
    var position04 = (scrollPercent04 * -($(document).width() - $stripe04.width()));      

    $stripe01.css({
        'left': position01
    });
    $stripe02.css({
        'left': position02
    });
    $stripe03.css({
        'right': position03
    });      
    $stripe04.css({
        'right': position03
    });      
    $stripe05.css({
        'right': position03
    });      
    $stripe06.css({
        'left': position04
    });      
});
});
```

Comment: Code reviews are best posted over at [CodeReview SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: ahh i see, i'm still new here, thanks